# Tkinter: Changing image of Radiobutton using another Radiobutton works only the first time

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am trying to create a game level editor. The program reads a binary file, associate the byte to a image and then, with a loop, it shows all the images in canvas (Canvas B). The images are Radiobutton. This part works properly.

Below (Canvas A) I have a set of images that are radiobuttons too. Here I choose the image I want to use by clicking on it. This image will be used to redesign the Canvas B Then I go to the Canvas B, decide which tile I want to change and click on it. And it works: the radiobutton has now the chosen image.
In fact it works every time but only the **first time**. If I change my mind and want to change a radiobutton already changed nothing happens.

I tried to understand what the problem is by printing the variable of the radiobutton with `.get()`and I see that it stored the value of the last rabiobutton clicked. I tried to reset this value even with `del` but it doesn't work.

Here's the code (canvas B)

```
img_list=[]
n_row = 0
n_col = 0
index = 0
x = IntVar()
for f in os.listdir(path):
    img_list.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(os.path.join(path,f))))
    n_col +=1
    index +=1
    if n_col > 21:
        n_row +=1
        n_col = 1
    tile = Radiobutton(A, image=img_list[index-1], indicatoron=0, bd=2, variable = x, value = index, selectcolor="red", command=several)
    tile.grid(row=n_row, column = n_col)
```

And here's Canvas A

```
    def erase():
        global val_t_e_x
        del val_t_e_x
        
        val_t_e_x=t_e_x.get()
        print(val_t_e_x)
        
        
    img_qui=[]
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        img_qui.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(os.path.join(path,f))))
    def several_editor():    
        global codice_bb
        global val_x
        global val_t_e_x
        val_t_e_x=t_e_x.get()    
        print(val_t_e_x)    
        row_qui=row_list[val_t_e_x-1]
        col_qui=col_list[val_t_e_x-1]   
        tile_editor=Radiobutton(B, image=img_qui[val_x-1], variable = val_t_e_x, value = rev, indicatoron=0, bd=0, selectcolor="blue",
                                  highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", command=erase)
        tile_editor.grid(row=row_qui, column=col_qui)
   
    col_b=0
    row_b=9
    l_editor=[]
    row_list=[]
    col_list=[]
    rev=0
    t_e_x = IntVar()
    
    for x, y in zip(line[::2], line[1::2]):
    
        a= ("./gfx/"+(x+y)+".png")
        row_b-=1
        rev+=1
        if row_b<1:
            col_b+=1
            row_b=8
        im = Image.open(a)
        ph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
        l_editor.append(ph)
        tile_editor = Radiobutton(B, image=l_editor[rev-1], variable = t_e_x, value = rev, indicatoron=0, bd=0, selectcolor="blue",
                                  highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", command=several_editor)
        tile_editor.grid(row=row_b, column=col_b)
        row_list.append(row_b)
        col_list.append(col_b)
```

I suppose that the problem is in the function def several_editor()

```
tile_editor=Radiobutton(B, image=img_qui[val_x-1], variable = val_t_e_x, value = rev, 
indicatoron=0, bd=0, selectcolor="blue", highlightbackground="black", 
highlightcolor="black", command=erase)
```

and that I am not handling the val_t_e_x variable properly.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: did You try using `onvalue` attribute to specify what number exactly is passed to the variable?

Comment: No, I did not. But I am sure it is storing the value of the last radiobutton selected (I print this value on the console). And also the rabiobutton reselected remains always selected.

Comment: so each radiobutton gives a different value?

Comment: The first time, yes. Every radiobutton has its correct number, But on reselection the number given is the last. So if I click on the first radiobutton I get 1, the second gives me 2, let's say the last is 3. If I try to reselect the first button the value I get is 3 and not 1 as expected.

Comment: ok, try using `onvalue` and set it to each button accordingly so for first `1`, second `2` and so on, this should certainly work

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to use `onvalue`. Could give me an example, please?

Comment: when creating `Radiobuttn` add attribute `onvalue=int` for example `Radiobutton(**options, onvalue=1)`, read more here: [link to source about `Radiobutton`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_radiobutton.htm)

Comment: Hi, Donatello, welcome to the community. Did you try using lambda on your function calls? `tile_editor = Radiobutton(B, ..., command=lambda: several_editor)`, that might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your function isn't returning is because you don't know what the input is for several_editor(). You need to anonymize it with [lambda](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp).
I'm going to provide a simple example of why this is necessary:

```py
import tkinter, os, sys
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class T():
    def __init__(self):
        labelstr=["ascii"]
        top = tkinter.Tk()
        top.geometry('200x50')
        top.title('lambda')
        for label in labelstr:
            self.lab = tkinter.Label(top, text=label, width=len(label)).grid(row=labelstr.index(label)+1, column=0)
            self.ent = tkinter.Entry(top, width=10).grid(row=labelstr.index(label)+1, column=1)
        but = tkinter.Button(top, text="submit", command=lambda: self.submit(top))
        but.grid(row=labelstr.index(label)+1, column=3)
        top.mainloop()

    def submit(self, frame):
        for i in frame.winfo_children():
            if i.winfo_class() == "Entry":
                i.delete(0, tkinter.END)
                i.insert(0, "HelloWorld!")
```

I can't really test the code where I am at the moment, but this should work.

The above is to provide a functional example of proper use of a lambda function within your code and demonstrate why you'd need it. Try removing the lambda and see that the function runs only once and will no longer run properly. This symptom should look familiar to you as it's exactly as you described it. Add the lambda back and the function runs again each time you hit the button.